# Can a Bamboo project be configured to use the Maven developers section to send build notifications?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, bamboo

I have a Maven project configured in [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) (version 5.3).  I would like to be able to use the [developers section](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Developers) in my pom.xml in order to send build notifications to the developers defined in that section.  This was possible in other Continuous Integration tools I have used before.  Is there a hook that can be used in Bamboo to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use maven project configuration for sending emails, use maven itself for this job. It will work for any environment and CI tool you choose.

1. Provide 'build-success' + 'build-failed' profiles with configured [maven-changes-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/) in your pom.xml.
2. Add corresponding calls into post-build handling:

   ```
   mvn changes:announcement-mail -P build-success # for successful build
   mvn changes:announcement-mail -P build-failure`# for failed build
   ```